How to catch a Reactor RetryExhaustedException?
I have code throwing a reactor.core.Exceptions$RetryExhaustedException and I would like to catch that specific exception.
However, this RetryExhaustedException is not a public class, it is a package-private static class on the public reactor.core.Exceptions-class, so I cannot just put it in a catch-statement. Since the exception extends IllegalStateException I could catch that, but that is a very broad exception that I would prefer not to generally handle.
(Note that I am not talking about the deprecated (public) class reactor.retry.RetryExhaustedException. That is not the same exception.)

I have accepted an answer that does precisely what I want, but I am open to the idea that I am in an XY-problem here (eg catching that exception is totally misguided) and I would appreciate answers in that direction.

The answer I have now accepted uses only the public reactor API so I am a bit more confident that what I am makes sense.

What I don't get is why a question so clear that it gets two different accurate answers from people who didn't need to comment on the question gets a close-vote for lacking clarity.

I think you could use util method Exceptions.isRetryExhausted(e) to check whether the given exception is RetryExhausted.
Also with that class you may check others exceptions from Exceptions class, see methods that start with is...

This is the way to go. Perfect.

I think you could do something like:
try {
    // Your reactive operations
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    if (e.getClass().getName().equals("reactor.core.Exceptions$RetryExhaustedException")) {
        // Handle the RetryExhaustedException case
    } else {
        throw e;  // rethrow the exception if it's not RetryExhaustedException
    }
}

but that is not so elegant. 

not elegant, but it does precisely what I want, which is to catch the exception without danger of swallowing unrelated exceptions.

However, I think I will change this to e.getClass().getName().contains("RetryExhaustedException"), which seems a bit more robust in case of a reactor-upgrade.

I have changed my accepted-badge to the other answer because it shows the way it's meant to be done. Still your answer is useful for other non-public exception-classes that may be thrown by any library. I will keep this trick up my sleeve, hoping I don't need it.
